# Is it possible to do a JOIN without knowing ON what column the JOIN is done?

Tags: mysql, join

Is there, for example, a function such as `SELECT t0.*, t1.* JOIN t1 ON t0.some_known_field = GET_PRIMARY_INDEX(t1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible, in pure SQL, to use any sort of variable or lookup to construct the names of tables or columns.

You can use "dynamic SQL" which is a fancy-sounding way of having a stored procedure construct a text string from queries and other information and then run it as a SQL statement. Or you can do the same in your application program.  Many SQL applications do this sort of thing.